# ajax request.done make the script broken?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax request using jquery. From the tutorial, I try this simple script:

```
function show(){
    $("#mesg").html("begin");

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some url",
        data: '{"user_name": "NAME"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    $("#mesg").html("waiting");

    request.done(function(){
        $("#mesg").html("done sending");
    });

    $("#mesg").html("still waiting");

    request.fail(function(){});

    $("#mesg").html("end of function");
}
```

So the request is supposed to fail and the content of #mesg should be "end of function". However, what I got was "waiting," which is before request.done(). So is there a syntax error here?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? If it's earlier than 1.5 `.ajax()` doesn't support the promise interface so I would think your script would crash when it tries to use `.done()` and that would be consistent with processing stopping at the "waiting" message. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: That's the problem!! Apparently I copied this from w3school: src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" and didn't notice that it's not up to date. Screw me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Since that worked I've posted my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a version of jQuery earlier than 1.5 `.ajax()` doesn't support the promise interface so I would think your script would crash when it tries to use `.done()` and that would be consistent with processing stopping at the "waiting" message.

Update to the latest version (or at least 1.5+) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Example from jquery documentation is like this. You have quotes around your data maybe remove those and remove the quotes around the parameter name, leaving just the value in quotes. and make sure your parameters names are correct.

You also should capture the "msg" that you get from a post. as in the example below.

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {id : menuId},
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
      $("#log").html( msg );
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
```

Comment: I'm not trying to actually send a request. It seems like I have problem with the syntax, the request is fine because I can get this line executed: $("#mesg").html("waiting");
However, I edit the data as you suggested to
data: {user_name: "NAME"}
and it still doesn't work. Or is it still incorrect put the data that way?
Thanks!

Comment: Try capturing the actual message in your done and fail request like above `request.done(function(msg) {...`